# How to get current date, month, year in scala

Tags: scala

i need current year, month & date to 3 different variables. below code gives date time

```
val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

> Thu Sep 29 18:27:38 IST 2016

but i need in YYYY MM and DD format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
val date =cal.get(Calendar.DATE )
val Year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR )
val Month1 =cal.get(Calendar.MONTH )
val Month = Month1+1
```

Month is added with one because month starts with zero index.

Answer (score 3):

When you are talking about `year`, `month`, `day-of-month`, `hour-of-day` etc... your timezone becomes very important. So whenever you are talking about all these, you have to mention the timezone.

If you are using java 8, you can use the java.time api

```
import java.time.{ZonedDateTime, ZonedOffset}

// val yourTimeZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutesSeconds(hour, minute, second)

// for example IST or Indian Standard Time has an offset of "+05:30:00" hrs

val istOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutesSeconds(5, 30, 0)
// istOffset: java.time.ZoneOffset = +05:30

// time representation in IST
val zonedDateTimeIst = ZonedDateTime.now(istOffset)
// zonedDateTimeIst: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2016-09-29T20:14:48.048+05:30

val year = zonedDateTimeIst.getYear
// year: Int = 2016

val month = zonedDateTimeIst.getMonth
// month: java.time.Month = SEPTEMBER

val dayOfMonth = zonedDateTimeIst.getDayOfMonth
// dayOfMonth: Int = 29

val df1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy - MM - dd")
val df2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
// df1: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)' ''-'' 'Value(MonthOfYear,2)' ''-'' 'Value(DayOfMonth,2)
// df2: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'/'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'/'Value(DayOfMonth,2)


val dateString1 = zonedDateTimeIst.format(df1)
// dateString1: String = 2016 - 09 - 29
val dateString2 = zonedDateTimeIst.format(df2)
// dateString2: String = 2016/09/29
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val date: String = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").print(DateTime.now())
val month: Int = DateTime.now().getMonthOfYear
val year: Int = DateTime.now().getYear
```

In case you use java8 you could also use the native DateTime API, which is designed after the joda-time api.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different SimpleDateFormat objects for that purpose as described [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-get-current-date-time-hour-calendar-example)

In your case, you'll need :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 

val minuteFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM")
val yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY")
val dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")
```

And then, to get for example, the year for a given date, simply use :

```
val currentYear = hourFormat.format(yourDate)
```